# onChange event not firing in a specific circumstance

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm using a module to convert uploaded files into base64 (https://github.com/adonespitogo/angular-base64-upload).

Basically I'm making it perform filetype and size validations prior to the base64 encoding. It's working perfectly except for a very specific situation.
When I upload a file and it does not validade (maximum size exceeded for example) it gives me a response (in the following plnkr it will be an alert for easy tracking). If I try to upload the exact same file again, it just doesn't fire the event. It doesn't get uploaded, but I don't get a response either.

```
.directive('baseSixtyFourInput', ['$window', function ($window) {
return {
  restrict: 'A',
  require: 'ngModel',
  scope: {
    maxSize: '=baseSixtyFourMaxSize',
    acceptedFormats: '=baseSixtyFourAcceptedFormats'
  },
  link: function (scope, elem, attrs, ngModel) {
    var fileObject = {};

    var abort = function (message) {
      alert(message);
      return false;
    };

    scope.readerOnload = function (e) {
      blah, blah...
    };

    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = scope.readerOnload;

    //THIS EVENT DOES NOT GET FIRED
    elem.on('change', function () {
      if (!elem[0].files.length) {
        return;
      }

      var file = elem[0].files[0];

      (validations here)

      fileObject.filetype = file.type;
      fileObject.filename = file.name;
      fileObject.filesize = file.size;
      reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
    });

    function _arrayBufferToBase64(buffer) {
      blah blah...
    }
  }
};
```

I have been trying to figure out why, and since it is triggered by a change in the 'elem', I tried to manually change it before the cicle ends, so if I try to upload the same file, the elem is different, and thus, changed.
I haven't had any success doing it, as apparently I can't edit it directly. I tried using $compile and .replaceWith() along with dozens of other attempts, without success.

Here's a [working plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/0nYgXtIQ8TSeX1p5t4vA).

(Notice that the input[button] keeps the name of the file. I believe the root of the problem is on how the HTML handles the file input... But in the end I don't mind about the the visual part because I'm styling the button, so that name will not appear)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I kept searching and eventually found out a way to clear it, using the input id.

On the abort function just added a cleaning routine right before it exits the application:

```
var abort = function (message) {
  alert(message);
  document.getElementById(elem[0].attributes[1].value).value = '';
  return false;
};
```

Here's the [updated plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/zdsVjpGbTfqv9hjkPxAu).

This will allow the cleaning of the input by id. The only issue is that you HAVE to have an id on the html element (which should always be there anyway), but you don't have to worry with it's name, as it will figure it out by the elem attributes.
Is there a cleaner way to perform this?